# Apple Wireless Keyboard on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, mac, keyboard, ctrl-alt-delete

I have a Turkish-Q layout Apple Wireless Keyboard (without keypad) connected to Windows 10. I cannot send Ctrl+Alt+Delete signal. I tried combinations like Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Backspace which apparently works for other users, but it did not work for me. Any ideas?

Comment: It may depend on the specific keyboard.   Turn on the 'on screen keyboard', you can then select ctrl, alt & del with the mouse. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try Fn/ctrl/alt/backspace
Fn/Backspace on Mac will send 'true' delete, the two keys are separate on an extended keyboard, on a short keyboard only Backspace exists

Backspace is Unicode 0x7f
Del is Unicode 0xf728

Fn/backspace should send 0xf728

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work either. Would you know how can I see what unicode signal do the individual keys send? Maybe I can figure out by checking the individual keys & combinations.

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea how to do that on Windows. On Mac you can use [Key Codes](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) (freeware)